# I am getting this error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function, apply

I have this table that in which I am comparing list of articles (`Article_body`) with 4 baseline articles using cosine similarity:

| Article_body | articleScores1 | articleScores2 | articleScores3 | articleScores4 | articleScores5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a***** | 0.6 | 0.2 | 0.7 | 0.9 | 0.2 |
| a***** | 0.3 | 0.8 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.1 |

I want to add a column that gives which column has the largest cosine similarity out of 5, condition it should be at least 0.5. If none of CosineSim(`i`)

| Article_body | articleScores1 | articleScores2 | articleScores3 | articleScores4 | Most_similar_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a***** | 0.6 | 0.2 | 0.7 | 0.9 | CosineSim4 |
| a***** | 0.3 | 0.8 | 0.1 | 0.5 | CosineSim2 |
| a****** | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | False |

I am using this code to achieve this:

```
cos_cols = [f"articleScores{i}" for i in range(1, 6)]    
def n_lar(text):
    if (df[cos_cols].idxmax(axis=1)) <0.5:
        return False
    
    else:
        df['Max'] = (df[cos_cols].idxmax(axis=1))

  
df['Most_similar_to'] = df.apply(n_lar)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

How can I resolve this?

edit:

I have this table that in which I am comparing list of articles (Article_body) with 4 baseline articles using cosine similarity:

I want to add a column that gives which column has the largest cosine similarity out of 5, condition it should be at least 0.5. If none of CosineSim(i) is atleast 0.5 then return False as in the table 2

Comment: The value in the selected column is a string, not a number.

Comment: thanks for your comment; however, there are only numbers in those selected columns

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `(df[cos_cols].idxmax(axis=1)) <0.5:` seems like a bug. `idxmax` returns a series of indices, which are integers. Why are you comparing it with `0.5`?

Comment: I want to compare with 0.5 and return False if max is less than 0.5

Comment: I have this table that in which I am comparing list of articles (Article_body) with 4 baseline articles using cosine similarity:

I want to add a column that gives which column has the largest cosine similarity out of 5, condition it should be at least 0.5. If none of CosineSim(i) is atleast 0.5 then return False as in the table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(df.iloc[:, 1:-1]
 .astype('float')
 .apply(
     lambda x: ('CosineSim' + x.idxmax()[-1]) if x.max() >= 0.5 else False 
     , axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
0    CosineSim4
1    CosineSim2
2         False
```

make result to `Most_similar_to` column